# Rspec allow_any_instance_of to return instance id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

Is it possible to do something like this???

```
allow_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:foo).and_return("hello #{instance.id}")
```

Can i return a message depending on the instance?

Comment: you can't do this with `allow_any_instance_of` rspec mocks, you can only mock single message or multiple messages of an instance using this. Can you share what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, using the "block" form of the matcher, which gives you access to the instance as the formal parameter to the block. You also need to make sure that `Object` (or whatever class you are passing to `allow...`) implements `:foo` (or whatever method you are specifying) as an instance method, or the `allow...` will raise an error. Similarly, of course, you need to make sure that `id` is implemented as well.

Here is some sample code using `Object` itself:

```
class Object
  def id
    'bar'
  end
  def foo
  end
end
describe '' do
  it '' do
    allow_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:foo) { |o| "hello #{o.id}" }
    puts Object.new.foo
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a gem like `factory_girl` or `fabrication` to generate test objects.

That will let you do...

```
this_object = Fabricate(:object)
expect(this_object).to receive(:foo).and_return("hello #{this_object.id}")
```